# Toggling value of variable assigned to checkbox in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, checkbox, toggle

I have a checkbox:

```
  <input type="checkbox" [checked]="passenger.luggage" (change)="passenger.luggage = ! passenger.luggage">Luggage
```

and I want to add +1 when it's checked to a variable assigned in components.ts:

```
public luggageCounter: number = 0;
```

I tried applying a function on change

```
luggageAdd() {
    this.luggageCounter++
  }
```

but it only adds +1 whenever the checkbox is clicked/changed. I'm looking for a solution where it adds +1 only when checked and if it's no longer checked it takes this +1 back.

Thanks for helping solve this!

Comment: Are you using Reactive Forms or Template Driven Forms?

Comment: Reactive - I'm keeping all of the logic in components.ts